# Can't run webapp on Tomcat, Error 51, although java -version is correct, Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, osx-mountain-lion

I installed Java 7 on my Mac, compiled a web-app, and now I am trying to run it on Tomcat. However, I get the nasty `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` error. Googling showed that it is because Tomcat is using Java 6 to run the app, which is compiled for Java 7.

So I tried setting the path to the Java 7 jre in my "catalina.sh" script, but it didn't help. Moreover, "java -version" returns the correct java version.

`dtv$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)`

How can I fix this?

Comment: try getting java6 instead

Comment: what is tomcat version? did you test your tomcat before deploying your war ?

Comment: @BhavikShah I already have Java6, my web app is written with the use of Java7 features, so i need to make it run on Java7

Comment: @Subin Tomcat version is 7.0.29. What do you mean by "test"? I checked that it runs the ROOT app.

Comment: can you post the prints while you start tomcat from console/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your JDK 7.  Catalina expects to find Java there.  See if that tells it how to get JDK 7.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I thought setting it in the catalina.sh would be enough, but I was wrong. Thank you.